# where is the best place to find resources about user interface design topics

Tags: user-interface

it might be a forum discussion about 3D & 2D Combined User Interface ideals, prototypes, resources.

i haven't find one suitable till now, any recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is the one and only place to find resources. Good websites are for example:

- [Great thoughts about simple and
  clean user interfaces out of an
  information architect's point of
  view.](http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/)
- [Many articles about web design,
  frontend-development, user
  interfaces, etc.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)
- [Some great articles about usability
  and related topics.](http://www.usabilitypost.com/)
- [Visual inspiration](http://www.infosthetics.com/)

… the list might be endless. Just google for some terms like "information architecture", "ixd", "ui/ux design", "usability", etc. — hope this helps you.